# How to connect in ssh with root privilege to a Windows terminal?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, terminal, windows-terminal

I'm trying to port forward localy by opening the port through ssh.

But the fact is for ports below 1024, you need to be in root.

So when I'm trying for example :

```
server-002@XXX.XX.X.X -L 80:localhost:80
```

that's what I get :

```
Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root.
```

I obviously can't add the command "sudo" in a windows terminal otherwise :

```
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So, my question is, how from the windows terminal can I use root privilege to port forward ports below 1024 ?

Update : starting the terminal as administrator doesn't change anything.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Try using: `-L 8080:localhost:80`.

Comment: hello @harrymc thank you ! yes indeed it is working. But my question is, how to port forward with root privileges port below 1024 from this windows terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the OpenSSH client that comes with Windows 10.

The Windows client must be an old version of OpenSSH,
because this check was removed from OpenSSH since 2019. See
[OpenSSH client is not able to forward a privileged port #1350](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1350).

I suggest to install OpenSSH and use its client, rather than that of Windows.

For future readers: The Windows solution would be
to use `-L 8080:localhost:80`.